# Bug in a tag that I added as a comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

So, I was posting a comment on an answer and I used [edit:] on the comment section. This generated a hyperlink on the comment line which when clicked opened up the option to edit the answer of the thread where I was commenting on.

You can see a live example here on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504152/is-it-possible-to-use-xdebug-on-ubuntu/5504181?noredirect=1#comment29149222_5504181).

Comment: And what's your point?

Comment: Try `edit:` or `[edit:]` instead.

Comment: Which also raises the question why you wanted that formatted as a tag in the first place?

Comment: If you want it formated as tag, use `[tag:c#]` -> [tag:c#] or for meta `[meta-tag:status-bydesign]` -> [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. \[edit:\] Looks better in a post.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby I guess the point is: here's some behaviour the OP doesn't understand, can you answer it without be dismissive.

Comment: Did I just miss something?!

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby I presume you were being sarcastic and condescending about me being ignorant and noobish about a feature which might is common knowledge. If that was not your intention, I apologise and take back my comment.

Comment: No, not this time. I had/have trouble understanding what your intention is (and there for your problem). Formatting "edit:" as a *tag* (that gray-boxed-thingies attached to questions) doesn't make much sense as far as I see, but maybe we mean something different?

Comment: I take back my comment. I though `[edit:]` looks visually appealing and was confused as to why the tag became a hyperlink to edit someone else's answer.

Comment: As it seems, you're using the word "tag" differently compared to what I have in mind. When you said something like "added this tag `[edit:]`" I assumed that you actually wanted it formatted like the tags attached to questions (see comment by Johannes). *That* was what was confusing to me, because formatting this text as *tag* (not putting into square-brackets) doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a [*feature*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). If you want to tell some one to edit the post you can simply use `[edit]` so it will link you to an edit page of that link. If you want to write [edit:] in the comment without linking to the edit page, just use backticks like this: ```[edit:]``` `` or simply use ```edit:`.

Comment: Why format \[edit:\] as code?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - Just to highlight it. But better to use **[edit:]** or the one you suggested instead. :)

Comment: ``\`` is the way to go. Btw, not that easy to get a ``\`` inside `\``

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.. Though it was hard to get it since I did not actually notice the feature list. Also, the use case seemed kinda redundant. Thanks though again